# Extracting a href using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Hey I am trying to extract this link:

https://aulib.abdn.ac.uk:443/F/PEYK3FS2A56KCUKNUE2DNC111QPYC4T1AIPEQ3VP7VXK27HHFM-41314?func=short-sort&set_number=010039

From this  [image: Screenshot]

I have tried using:

```
 Elements headings = doc.select("th:eq(2)");
```

But that seams to reutn the whole line instead of just the link. My question is how would I extract only the link?

Thank you

Comment: The picture is barely legible.. maybe imgur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `doc.select("th:eq(2) > a").first().attr("href")`